# get data from mongo db in mean stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

this is my api, i want to get data from mongo db..

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
   var ct2 = require('../controller/load_msg');
        router.get('/display_msgs',function(req, res) {
       res.send('api works!');
    });

   module.exports = router;
```

my api is working fine .
at this http://localhost:3000/api/display_msgs

now dont know the further works.. help me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Mongo DB in your project, maybe you can try the `Mongoose` library.

You can check the [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/) for more infomation.